# How to Access A MC Question User Selection JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

how would I access the value of the radio mc choice (chosen by the user) through JS. For example, for this snippet from w3 schools

```
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
  <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
  <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
  <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
```

Please respond if you have an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "mc choice"?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of `radio` button by `querySelector()` method *(There are other ways too)*. Add **CSS** for checked radio button in `querySelector()` method.

To avoid errors check if user selected any one of radio button. And then you're good to go.

```js
let getValueBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
let output = document.getElementById("radioValue");

const getValue = () => {
  const radioBtnValue = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="fav_language"]:checked');
  
  if(radioBtnValue === null) return `Nothing is Selected`;
  
  return radioBtnValue.value;
}

getValueBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const radioValue = getValue();
  output.innerText = radioValue;
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
<label for="html">HTML</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
<label for="css">CSS</label><br>

<input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
<label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>

<br>
<br>

<button id="btn">Get Value</button>

<p id="radioValue"></p>
```